# Best way to notify user that jobs is done using RabbitMQ and WebSockets

Tags: php, python, yii2, rabbitmq

I'm using Yii2 and yii2-queue extension to push jobs in RabbitMQ in some queue.
These jobs are importing xls|csv files to the database. At the end of job I send message to another queue - listens by python pika, and send to client by websocket.

**php, piece of Job code, that sends new message**

```
if (!empty($imported)) {

            $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($queue->host, $queue->port, $queue->user, $queue->password);
            $channel = $connection->channel();

            $channel->queue_declare('import_queue', true, true, false, false);

            $message = 'Catalog, imported items: ' . count($imported);
            $message = new AMQPMessage($message, [
                'content_type' => 'text/plain',
                'delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT
            ]);

            $channel->basic_publish(
                $message, '', 'import_queue'
            );

            $channel->close();
            $connection->close();
        }
```

**python code.**

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost',
                                       5672,
                                       '/',
                                       credentials)

amqp_conn = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
amqp_ch = amqp_conn.channel()

def threaded_rmq():
    amqp_ch.queue_declare(queue="import_queue", durable=True)
    amqp_ch.basic_consume(callback, queue="import_queue", no_ack=True)
    amqp_ch.start_consuming()


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    data = {'type': 'imported_catalog_items', 'message': body}
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    for client in clients:
        client.sendMessage(u'' + json_data)

def disconnect_to_rabbitmq():
    amqp_ch.stop_consuming()
    amqp_conn.close()
```

**The problem:** 
I don't know when the last job will be done. 
When user sends file, I block the html form and apply loader icon.
I set session var to block this. I want to unblock the form, (remove the loader) when all jobs will be executed, and notify user that "Import jobs is done".

What is the best way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: what's the point of using a background job, if you block the UI.  To me that is the whole purpose to use a background job.

Comment: I've updated my question. I want to unlock form, when all jobs will be executed

Comment: That makes more sense, we Use Rabbit, but we have a progress bar that we display.  For this we just use the database, and AJAX, but we have to track other stuff ( for billing on jobs ) using the DB so that may not make sense in your case.

Comment: That said I do know a nifty trick to count the lines in a CSV using SplFileObject, which we use to get the total rows.  Then we increment a counter every nth line for the progress percent.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes, using progress-bar and AJAX calls it is a good idea, we have several modules in our project which works that way. We use this case when a csv or xls file is not too big or we don't want to make with this data complex handling (save to DB, upload images from file, more relation logic, etc.).

We decide to use background jobs to import catalog items - more than 5000 items, and for each item is necessary to upload images, save many fields to DB. And I don't know how to make it possible to get message from Rabbit when jobs is all done.

Comment: we use it to do searches against our data, were up to 160k csv rows a minute on one server and adding a second one soon...  More than that I cant say I have a NDA ( sorry )

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for your response. I didn't sleep at least 20 hours and my brain refused to think clearly. 
I've just find solution that works for our project. Its simple: When we creating jobs for parsing and importing files, - we put flag 'isLastJob'. And when the job will be executed -> we unblock the ui (form), reset session vars, and it's ready to handle next file. 
thanks again! good luck && happy code!

Comment: Yea I been thinking of using JSON for my framework too, so it's a good choice.

Comment: glad you got it worked out, good luck to you too!